# Grequests with multiple JSON payloads

Tags: python, json, google-api, python-requests, grequests

I'm trying to simultaneously send multiple POST requests with JSON payloads and retrieve the JSON results. I've read a few other posts on SO but nothing is doing the trick.

```
def transcribe(vid_segs):
   payloads = []
   for vid in vid_segs:
      vid = base64.b64encode(open(vid).read())
      payload = {
      "config": {
            "encoding": "LINEAR16",
            "sampleRateHertz": 16000,
            "languageCode": "en-US",
            "speechContexts": {
                "phrases:": ["Barack", "Obama", "Barack Obama"]
            }
        },
        "audio": {
            "content": vid
        }
    }
    payloads.append(payload)

   url = "https://speech.googleapis.com/v1/speech:recognize?key=MYAPIKEY"
   unsent_request = []
   for payload_single in payloads:
      unsent_request.append(grequests.get(url,
                                        params=payload_single))
   responses = grequests.map(unsent_request)
   for response in responses:
      print response.json()
      response.close()
```

If I use response.json(), it returns the error:

```
JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

If I try with response.json, what's returned isn't the actual JSON content, just the object details and the response code:

```
<bound method Response.json of <Response [404]>>
```

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: First thing that gets my attention is that 404, maybe the URL is ... wrong, malformed or incomplete? Does sending only 1 payload works ? Seen that you get a `JSONDecodeError` that might be because the response is not JSON (which seems reasonable seen the 404), try debugging/see the `response` object in some other way (print, dir, .. or just use a debugger: pdb or whatever your IDE can offer )

Answer (score 0):

`response.json` is a method, so you need to call it: `response.json()`. The `JSONDecodeError` is telling you that the response isn't valid JSON. Try printing `response.text` (the response as text) or `response.content` (binary response) to see what the response actually consists of.

As @Lohmar ASHAR points out in a comment, you're getting a 404, so it's probably not suprising you're not getting JSON back.

More on responses: http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#response-content

Comment: Thanks Brian and @Lohmar. You're right about the 404 code - it's not actually getting a response from the API. So I guess the question should really be about the way I am going about the request in general. I've verified that everything is good with the URL and the parameters - if I try one at a time, it works fine.